# Turn a file name into a clickable list

Tags: html

I need to turn the name of the file in the folder into a clickable text. As of now, the file name is in one line and link in another.

What's the name of it? Which keywords I should use?

```py
html = '<html><body>' 

subset = []
lastFile = None
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".html"):
        subset.append(file)
for r in subset:
    if not lastFile:
        html += '<h3>%s</h3>' % r
    html += '<a href="%s">r</a>' % r
```

Comment: Give us your actual results... What is the content of the list `subset` ? (give us a sample)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap the `<h3>` tag in an anchor tag, using your code do something like this

```
html = '<html><body>' 

subset = []
lastFile = None
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".html"):
        subset.append(file)
for r in subset:
    if not lastFile:
        html += '<a href="%s">' % r
    html += '<h3>%s</h3></a>' % r
```